# irs2453 - what type of wave and what maximum possible frequency

Tags: mosfet, inverter, mosfet-driver

I need to design a 10KHz 310V DC to 220V AC inverter.
After searching a lot on the web, I finally found the following DIY circuit based on the irs2453 chip:
[irs2453 based circuit](https://www.homemade-circuits.com/?s=Simplest%20Full%20Bridge%20Inverter%20Circuit)

Then I had a look at the irs2453 IC datasheet. This is once more an example of datasheet that says everything but what the IC exactly do (for the non specialist): This IC incorporates a timer and allows some oscillating mechanism to take place. But what kind of wave does it produce ? a square wave with 50% duty cycle, a triangular wave ? other ? also, it is unclear for me at what maximum frequency the IC can work. Some help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet for the [IRS2453](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irs2453d.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567ac42f2814) is fairly straightforward.

Since the device is a bridge driver output, it produces a square wave (or at least a PWM defined) output.

The maximum frequency of the onboard 555 is about 100 kHz. 
[image]

And the duty cycle about 50%

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, someone has downvoted this question (and I hate this) so I will delete the question.

Comment: Just ignore the downvote....some folks are very pedantic.